# Use titanium web proxy with mulitple outgoing ips

Tags: titanium-web-proxy

Is it possible to set the outgoing ip address in titanium web proxy?

I am currently using squid with a config like this:

```
acl r_6 random 1/6
acl r_5 random 1/5
acl r_4 random 1/4
acl r_3 random 1/3
acl r_2 random 1/2

tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.1.110 r_6
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.1.111 r_5
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.1.112 r_4
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.1.113 r_3
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.1.114 r_2
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.1.115
```

Is this possible. And instead of random I would rather make my own schedule. Which I found to be quite hard in squid config.